# Is it possible to store some lists with different length in one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some lists with different length and I am going to store them in one dataframe.

```
list1=[('G06F', 'H04L'),('H04N','G06F')]
list2=[('E06F', 'T08L'),('H05M', 'H03D'),('A05V', 'N03D')]
list3=[('M04F', 'A01B')]
```

I have been trying to have these lists in a dataframe coming with one row for each list.
I used `mylist.append()`, but it put the new list in one element after the former one

```
 list2.append(simple_list1)
 >>out:
 [('E06F', 'T08L'), ('H05M', 'H03D'), ('A05V', 'N03D'), [('G06F', 'H04L'), ('H04N', 'G06F')]]
```

Comment: You can simply enclose the lists with square brackets to create a list of lists: `[list1, list2, list3]`. To make it dataframe, just do: `pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([list1, list2, list3]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
list1=[('G06F', 'H04L'),('H04N','G06F')]    
list2=[('E06F', 'T08L'),('H05M', 'H03D'),('A05V', 'N03D')]    
list3=[('M04F', 'A01B')]    
list_combied = pd.DataFrame([[list1, list2, list3]]).T    
list_combied


0   [(G06F, H04L), (H04N, G06F)]    
1   [(E06F, T08L), (H05M, H03D), (A05V, N03D)]  
2   [(M04F, A01B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `+`

```
list1=[('G06F', 'H04L'),('H04N','G06F')]
list2=[('E06F', 'T08L'),('H05M', 'H03D'),('A05V', 'N03D')]
list3=[('M04F', 'A01B')]
lists = list1 + list2 + list3
print (lists)
```

The result is

```
[('G06F', 'H04L'), ('H04N', 'G06F'), ('E06F', 'T08L'), ('H05M', 'H03D'), ('A05V', 'N03D'), ('M04F', 'A01B')]
```